# Char limit in RichTextEditor

Tags: c#, tinymce, custom-controls, umbraco

I am trying to develop a custom control for Umbraco that would allow us to dynamically set the length of text allowed in TinyMCE. I have already implemented something similar for a normal text box but I am stuck on how to implement it with the RTE. I found no .dll that I could reference and although there is a little bit of [code on their site](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/How_to_limit_number_of_characters/words); it is only concerned with the javascript.

Any ideas on where to start would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a tinymce init parameter "max_chars" yourself

```
tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   max_chars : "10", // place your char limit here
   setup : function(ed) {
      ed.onKeyDown.add(function(ed, evt) {

        if ( $(ed.getBody()).text().length > ed.getParam('max_char')){
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
          return false;
        } 

      });
   },
   ...
});
```

Comment: The problem is that I am trying to implement it as a dataType in Umbraco. I don't really have access to the html to display it and there will be multiple versions of the RTE.

Comment: you do not have access to the html - this is javascript and is used to initialize the editor - there will be a place for configuring tinymce in umbraco!

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid: Did you find the place to add this code?